# Error al ingresar datos al arraylist dice cant resolve symbol

Tags: java, android-studio

La idea es un Listview que muestra los cuadros de un museo. al meter el array con los cuadros me da error, no entiendo porque tengo un ejercicio parecido y no me da error.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList datos = new ArrayList();
    private ListView listCuadros;
    private AdaptadorCuadros adaptador;
    private Context contexto;
    private View tv1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        contexto = this;
        datos.add(new Cuadros(titulo:"La Mona Lisa",autor:"Leonardo da Vinci",estilo:"Renacentista",precio:"$713 millones",fecha:"1503");
    }
}
```

Esta es la clase cuadros

```
public class Cuadros {
private String titulo;
private String autor;
private String estilo;
private String precio;
private String fecha;

public Cuadros(String titulo, String autor, String estilo, String precio, String fecha) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
    this.autor = autor;
    this.estilo = estilo;
    this.precio = precio;
    this.fecha = fecha;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getAutor() {
    return autor;
}

public void setAutor(String autor) {
    this.autor = autor;
}

public String getEstilo() {
    return estilo;
}

public void setEstilo(String estilo) {
    this.estilo = estilo;
}

public String getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(String precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}

public String getFecha() {
    return fecha;
}

public void setFecha(String fecha) {
    this.fecha = this.fecha;
}
```

Y esta es la clase adaptadora para el lisview

> public class AdaptadorCuadros extends ArrayAdapter {
>       private Activity context;
>       private ArrayList datos;

```
AdaptadorCuadros(Activity context, ArrayList datos) {
    super(context, R.layout.listview, datos);
    this.context = context;
    this.datos = datos;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View item = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (item == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
        holder.titulo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvTitulo);
        holder.autor = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvAutor);
        holder.precio = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvPrecio);
        holder.estilo = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvEstilo);
        holder.fecha = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvFecha);
        item.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) item.getTag();
    }
    holder.titulo.setText(datos.get(position).getTitulo());
    holder.autor.setText(datos.get(position).getAutor());
    holder.precio.setText(datos.get(position).getAutor());
    holder.estilo.setText(datos.get(position).getEstilo());
    holder.fecha.setText(datos.get(position).getFecha());
    return (item);
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titulo;
    TextView autor;
    TextView precio;
    TextView estilo;
    TextView fecha;
}
```

Uso android 7.1.1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En el `add`  cuando creas el objeto, tienes que pasar **únicamente las cadenas a `new`**, no se por qué le pasas los nombres de cada campo ¿? Intenta así: **`datos.add(new Cuadros("La Mona Lisa","Leonardo da Vinci","Renacentista","$713 millones","1503"));`**

Comment: Pues porque en el otro ejercicio lo tengo asi jaja voy probarlo gracias. Me explican muy mal en clase solo readapto codigo.
Era eso muchas gracias te debo 2 ya :P

Comment: Y también te faltaba un paréntesis de cierre. Ya lo puse bien en el anterior comentario.